# Why allow to return a value from __init__ with super in Python?

Tags: python, class, init, super

From [the documentation of](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__init__)  __init__

> no non-None value may be returned by __init__(); doing so will cause a TypeError to be raised at runtime.

and I found this code from a framework's extendable base class.

It runs without a runtime error.

```py
class Parent():
    def __init__(self, x):
        self.x = x
        return self.x + 10

class Child(Parent):
    def __init__(self, x):
        y = super(Child, self).__init__(x)
        print(y)

c = Child(5)
```

I searched about it and agreed that could be nice to pass data from super().__init__ to the derived class without having to relay it through an instance.

But, Why python allows the __init__ return value?

Is it a widely known pattern?

Comment: Please link the documentation where you found the information that you are quoting.

Comment: I think it's `type.__call__` that detects when `__init__` returns a value. In `Child`, you are calling `__init__` yourself and not caring that it returns an `int`.

Comment: @khelwood: I think so too, but [it's written](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__init__) in a similar way at least

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__init__ has a different wording: "Because __new__() and __init__() work together in constructing objects (__new__() to create it, and __init__() to customize it), no non-None value may be returned by __init__(); doing so will cause a TypeError to be raised at runtime."

Comment: I think the code you found would error if you tried to instantiate `Parent` directly.

Comment: @khelwood It does.

Comment: Other programming languages don't even allow this syntactically. And I never missed it in 17 years of programming. I don't see why such a feature would be needed in Python.

Comment: I found this code from a framework's extendable base class.
I'm a little bit shame, but now I understand why it works without a runtime error. Thanks all.

Comment: The more natural way to pass information between classes would be to write *some other* method in `Parent` that returns the value you want in `Child.__init__`.

Answer (score 1):

When a class is instantiated, python looks for a method called `__init__` and uses it in setting up the new class. If this method returns anything other than `None` here, it will raise an error:

```
class Parent():
    def __init__(self, x):
        self.x = x
        return self.x + 10

Parent(5)
# TypeError: __init__() should return None, not 'int'
```

However, in your child class you don't let Python use the `__init__` method in `Parent` - instead you override it by creating your own `__init__` which doesn't return anything.

You then call the `Parent` `__init__` method (via `super`) but here you are just calling it as a 'normal' method, rather than using it as part of the class setup, so it won't raise the error.